# Will my non-HDMI monitor be useless with laptops that don't support VGA?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, vga

I just bought in a Acer V243HL Monitor and realised that it hasn't got a HDMI input so I have connected it to my laptop via VGA cable. Although I like the quality of the display I am still worried that there is no HDMI input there in the monitor and so what if the future laptops and computers stop coming with the VGA out port.

Answer (score 3):

Your screen has *DVI* input according to [Acer](http://support.acer.com/acerpanam/MONITOR/2009/Acer/V243HL/V243HLsp2.shtml). You can simply use an HDMI-to-DVI adapter cable to connect it digitally to your current system. You can even convert DisplayPort to DVI using a cheap adapter cable.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I am happy with VGA it self however I am worried about if the VGA port is not supported in the future ?

Comment: @simi Unless the DVI input is broken, there's no need to use VGA. And as I wrote, all currently common output connectors, including the DisplayPort, which has only been in common use for ~1 year or so, can easily be connected to DVI input.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't replace it if the only thing that you dislike is the lack of HDMI. [DVI to HDMI adapters](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=104&cp_id=10419&cs_id=1041902&p_id=2029&seq=1&format=2) do a perfect job with zero quality loss. The only reason to get HDMI over DVI is for the sound, and external speakers will always trump monitor speakers.

Comment: He *doesn't* have HDMI input.

Answer (score 0):

You should be just fine to use the monitor. No need to get rid of it.

It is going to be a while before computer manufacturers completely do away with VGA output. There are far too many applicable devices to just stop using VGA. Besides, there are many types of adapters available to assist compatibility.

It will also be a long time before DVI is taken over completely by HDMI. Many new computers come with multiple type connections to give the user options for the vast array of displays available today.